# Is there a way to force a character encoding on Immutant 2/Undertow in Clojure?

Tags: utf-8, clojure, undertow

Is there any way to force a character encoding on Immutant 2/Undertow in Clojure? I am using Immutant 2 (2.0.0-alpha2) for my web application that serves web pages in Japanese in UTF-8, and, although the application runs perfectly fine in REPL on Eclipse, Immutant 2 converts HTTP response bodies into Shift_JIS, the default character encoding for non-Unicode applications in my Windows setup, once I convert the app into an uberjar.

I strongly suspect that this is a bug in Immutant 2/Undertow as UTF-8 is specified in the response header and this problem never occurred with Jetty and HTTP Kit. I would appreciate any pointers at this point as I spent the whole day today on this issue and I am almost ready to give up on Immutant 2 and go back to HTTP Kit.

Comment: Have you already tried specifying `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on the command line when running the uberjar? Might work around the issue but I agree, your observed behaviour seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting a possible workaround! I will try it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/IMMUTANT-506). I just pushed a fix that you can confirm using the latest [incremental](https://projectodd.ci.cloudbees.com/job/immutant2-incremental/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/apidocs/guide-installation.html).

Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for the report!

Comment: I just confirmed that this bug was resolved in 2.x.incremental.373. Thanks a bunch!